# Connection activation failed (32) Not authorized to control networking

Tags: networking, upgrade, connection

I made the decision to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 via 14.10 as I'd been having a few issues with 14.04, so I ran the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`. All seemed to go well, until tried to connect to wifi. I got the error Connection activation failed, so I tried a wired connection and got the same error. The question has been asked before but the answer did not work for me.

Here is what I have tried
 `usermod -G netdev -a jack` log out, log in.. reboot etc lots of times as root and as my user.

`nmcli dev wifi connect [wifi-name] pasword [password]` using the correct credentials obvs.

`nm-applet` as root

Removed the ssid as root with `nm-connection-manager`

I cannot find any other help for this. I cannot now upgrade further to 15.04. There is nothing in syslog in regards to network only mysqld error entries. Im at my wits end with this problem, I really dont want to have manually install 15.04 from .iso as I now only have internet on my mobile....

Please help.